# All text in HTML webpage has turned to a link pointing to a specific element id in the page. How to fix?

Tags: html

Sorry if this is a stupid question; this is the first coding project I have ever tried to do.

I tried to put a few links at the top of my page that would each point to and scroll down to a specific element/section on the page, but when I did that, 90% of the entire page has turned into a link that points to one specific section ("Favorite Memories" section) on the page. When I say the whole page is a "link", I mean that the mouse pointer is a pointer-finger wherever I go on the page, and it all points to the same section (I can click anywhere on the page, even clicking play on my video, and it will jump down to the "Favorite Memories" section). I can't figure out why this happened or to change it so the whole page isn't acting as a "link".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code (I erased all of the actual text so that it isn't so long):

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="intro-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Birthday Video</li>
            <li><a href="#reasons" class="nav-link">50 Things I Love About You</li>
            <li><a href="#memories" class="nav-link">Favorite Memories</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="intro-div">
          <h1>Te amo.</h1>
          <hr class="style15">
          <p class="tagline">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="video-div">
        <h2 class="video_title" id="video">Feliz Cumplea&ntilde;os, Hermosa M&iacute;a!</h2>
        <video width="500" height="400" controls>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>


    <div class="reasons-div">
        <h2 class="reasons-title" id="reasons">50 Things I Love About You</h2>
        <p class="reasons-text">
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="memories-div">
        <h2 class="memories-title" id="memories">My Top 10 Favorite Memories Together</h2>

        <div class="box-text">
            <p class="memories-text">
            </p>    
        </div>

        <div class="box-pics">
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>


    <div class="end_div">
        <p class="end_text">
        </p>
        <hr class="style15">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed your link tags:

```
<li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Birthday Video</li>
<li><a href="#reasons" class="nav-link">50 Things I Love About You</li>
<li><a href="#memories" class="nav-link">Favorite Memories</li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Birthday Video</a></li>
<li><a href="#reasons" class="nav-link">50 Things I Love About You</a></li>
<li><a href="#memories" class="nav-link">Favorite Memories</a></li>
```

Comment: Wow I feel dumb! I've been staring at it for the past hour and I didn't notice that. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happens to all of us sometimes... :p Glad I could help!